# Can 'zpopmax' be used with redis-py-cluster?

Tags: python, redis, redis-cluster

I'm trying to use `zpopmax` with a sorted set in python `rediscluster` [(repo)](https://github.com/Grokzen/redis-py-cluster), but the very simple program below fails with `AttributeError`.

**Question**: How can I implement `zpopmax` with `rediscluster`? 
If it's really not implemented, I'll have to use both `zrevrange` and `zrem` in a transaction to ensure thread safety.

### Possibly useful background

I've noticed the command is available in regular (not clustered) [redis-py](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=lock#redis.Redis.zpopmax). I also see the command [tested in the git repo](https://github.com/Grokzen/redis-py-cluster/search?q=zpopmax&unscoped_q=zpopmax) so I may be missing something easy.

I also tried `zpopmax` using regular `redis` and get the same error.

My [reids-py-cluster](https://github.com/Grokzen/redis-py-cluster) is v1.3.6. My [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) is v2.10.6. My [actual Redis](https://redis.io/) is v5.0.4

### Code

```
    from rediscluster import StrictRedisCluster as s

    rc = s(startup_nodes=[{'host': 'localhost', 'port': '7000'}],
           decode_responses=True)
    rc.zadd('my-set-name', 3, 'my-key-name')

    # print to confirm zadd worked
    print(rc.zrange('my-set-name', 0, -1, withscores=True)) 

    # expecting this to print 'my-key-name'
    print(rc.zpopmax('my-set-name')) # Attribute Error
```

I expect the output of the last print statement to be something like 'my-key-name` but I'm getting an AttributeError

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that redis-py added [support for `ZPOPMAX`](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/d811ae71dbdbeeb4fc0ee73a96b7fbdb1aec8522/CHANGES#L199) in version 3.0, but redis-py-cluster 1.3.6 [requires](https://github.com/Grokzen/redis-py-cluster/blob/1.3.6/docs/index.rst#dependencies--supported-python-versions) an older version of redis-py.

The easiest solution here is probably just to wait for redis-py-cluster to be updated. The problems caused by this pinning have been [acknowledged](https://github.com/Grokzen/redis-py-cluster/issues/326), and the next version will [add support](https://github.com/Grokzen/redis-py-cluster/blob/2.0.0/docs/index.rst#library-dependencies) for redis-py 3.0.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you help me understand how 1) [redis-py-cluster](https://github.com/Grokzen/redis-py-cluster), 2) [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) and 3) [actual Redis](https://redis.io/) work together? For those three, I have versions v1.3.6, v2.10.6, and v5.0.4 respectively. So I _think_ if any versions are wrong, it wouldn't be "actual Redis". I'll edit to add that info in my question.

Comment: @DanPittsley: You're welcome. I've updated the answer based on the new information.

Comment: Got it. Based on the great info you provided, I *was* actually able to get `zpopmax()` working by updating my versions. I need redis-py-cluser v2.0.0 and redis v3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Versions! As documented in Kevin's answer, versions are the issue here. However, I *can* actually get things working with this setup:

- [redis-py-cluser](https://github.com/Grokzen/redis-py-cluster/tree/2.0.0) v2.0.0
- [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/releases/tag/3.0.1) v3.0.1
- [Actual Redis](https://redis.io/) v5.0.4

### Code

```py
from rediscluster import RedisCluster as s

rc = s(startup_nodes=[{'host': 'localhost', 'port': '7000'}],
       decode_responses=True)
rc.zadd('my-set-name', {'my-key-name':3})

print(rc.zpopmax('my-set-name')) # WORKS! (prints [('my-key-name', 3.0)])
```

Thanks to [Kevin Christopher Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2395796/kevin-christopher-henry) for help getting there.